# How to Call the function with class name or onClick event in google chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension, in that, in the content script, I call the function using jQuery. The function can call only the first element of that class another element with the same class name it cannot work.
Then next time, I use onClick event on anchor tag is also not working.

```
switch (params.case) {

  case 1:
    if ($('#subvalue_MOBILE').text() != '') {       

      var img = '<img id="textsms" class="textsms" style="display:block; cursor:pointer;" src="' + chrome.extension.getURL(params.icon) + '"/>'; 

      btn = '<a onclick="sendtext()" class="' + classes + '" ' + style + ' target="' + params.target + '">';

      btn += '<span class="' + params.icon + '">' + img + '</span>'

      btn += params.text;

      btn += '</a>'             
    }
  break;

  case 2:
  {
    Another Code.
  }
}

$(document).on("click", ".textsms", function() {
  var mod = smsmodal();
  $('body').append(mod); 
});

function sendtext()
{
  var mod = smsmodal();
  $('body').append(mod); 
}
```

I want to call that function either using the class name or any other way.

Comment: can you create the snippest. Or just paste entire code in question.

Comment: Hi Sandy, ID should be unique in your loop same ID repeating for all img tag remove ID. If it is not looping  call event with ID

Comment: Image is looping every time when it access the particular textbox. I removed the ID as you said but still it will not work. According to Class Name the function call on first element or image shown in a textbox, but when the image shown in the next textbox at that time function can not be executed when I click on that image..

Comment: @Devsi Odedra  I just past entire code in question.

Comment: @mepraveenk : I can also use this jQuery function, so it will excute the function every click where the span tag exist.
I want click event only where image is placed every time.
Function :

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("span").click(function(){
    var modal = renderSMSmodal();
$('body').append(modal); 
  });
});